# How to get the data from a Laravel relationship without loading it onto the initial model

Tags: laravel

I realize the title may be a bit unclear so here's an example. Say I have a User and a Post. A User has many Posts. How would I get the posts without adding a posts field to the User Model.

EDIT:

I realize now that my question was unclear. I understand fully how to define the relations, my question is given the following code

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->with('posts')
```

What happens here is that `$user` now has a property called posts which contains all the posts belonging to the user. I don't want this. I want do something like the following

```
$user = User::where('id', 1);
$posts = $user->posts;
return response(['user' => $user, 'posts' => $posts])
```

The issue is that `$user` still has the posts property. I don't want it to have that.

EDIT
What I mean by having the posts property is as follows

Before calling $user->posts `$user` looks like:

```
['id' => 1, 'name' => 'jacob']
```

After calling `$user->posts`

```
$user = ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'jacob', 'posts' => ['id' => 1, 'user_id' => 1]]
```

I want a method of retrieving the posts **without** modifying the $user object

Comment: Check one to many relationship from the docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Or many-to-many if a Post can also have many Users. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: there wouldn't be anything on the `users` table for this relationship anyway ... you would only have a foreign key on `posts` that points to `users.id`

Comment: Edited the original question for more clarity

Comment: Could you not just do `$posts = Post::where('user_id', 1)->get();`? You don't need to query from the base model to the relationship if you don't want to.

Comment: I could, but my actual use case is more complicated. For example, each post has many comments and each comment has many reactions. So I don't want to have to write a bunch of loops to query manually.

Comment: Fair enough I guess; I'll take your word for it, but I'm not sure why you'd have to do manual queries in a loop for that either :) I would expect your `Post` model to have other relationships, like `Post::where('user_id', 1)->with(['comments', 'reactions'])->get()`, etc. You'd likely have to do that if you did `$user->posts()->with(...)->get();` etc etc.

Comment: Yes, but I want a flat structure for all of the entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edit

Use laravel collection [forget()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-forget)

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->with('posts')->first();
$posts = $user->posts;
$user = collect($user)->forgot('posts')->all(); // this is what you must do. Be careful, this is now an array.
return response(['user' => $user, 'posts' => $posts]);
```

---

**users** table

```
id  |  name
1   |  John
2   |  Adam
```

**posts** table

```
id  |  user_id  | title
1   |     1     | post_1
2   |     3     | post_2
3   |     1     | post_3
```

---

In this case, a user **has many** posts. And a post **belongs to** a user.

**User::class**

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class); // this will bind 'user_id' from the posts table to the 'id' of the users table
}
```

**Post::class**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

---

Then, you can simply access a user's post via

```
@foreach($user->posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Edited the original question for more clarity

Comment: @Jacob Check now. `forget()` can help you with such requirement.

Comment: Will `forget` work even if there are multiple users each with multiple posts?

Comment: @Jacob ```forget``` is for collections ```makeHidden``` is for models.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the data most efficiently from the db and end up with "flat" arrays, you should still use the relationships to retrieve them like:

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->first();
$posts = $user->posts;
return response(['user' => $user->makeHidden('posts'), 'posts' => $posts])
```

If you don't want to use relationships for some reason

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->first();
$posts = Post::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
return response(['user' => $user, 'posts' => $posts])
```

Comment: Edited the original question for more clarity

Comment: Yes, I gave that example to illustrate my point. Basically, I don't want a nested data structure. I want it to be flat.

Comment: Let me phrase my question differently. Is there, to your knowledge a method that can retrieve a entities relationships without modifying the original entity? (something like $user->posts, but one that just returns the posts without adding a posts property to the user data)

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this by use resources

1-first create new user resource:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class User extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "user"=>[
              'id' => $this->id,
              'name' => $this->name,
              'email' => $this->email,  
              ],
            "posts"=>$this->posts
        ];
    }
}
```

2-in your controller :

```
 $users = User::with('posts')->get()
 return UserResource::collection($users);
```

[laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections)

Answer (score 0):

using unset method, posts relation will be removed:

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->first();
$posts = $user->posts;
// remove posts relation from user collection
unset($user->posts);
return response(['user' => $user->makeHidden('posts'), 'posts' => $posts]);
```